# How do I use a mobile phone's GPS to locate a person and display that location on a website?

Tags: mobile, gps, tracking

I want to be able to **track a person** through their mobile phone and 
**display** those whereabouts **on a website**. I read some stuff here about Safari and iPhone.

What I need is a starting point in the sense of **what is possible**, and
if it is only possible for certain phones. I can ask a lot of specific questions as I've read bits and pieces everywhere, but what I need is a **general layout** of what needs to be done and, if possible **some of the steps** to accomplish it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we assume you are starting from scratch, here is a high level list of things to figure out:

- familiarise yourself with geolocation coordinates and the gps system. If you need to make sense of the raw location data, there is some math involved.
- pick a location-aware mobile platform. Some phones will implement jsr-179, which is a JavaME API. In addition, you can get location data using python or C++ on Symbian phones. I suspect Android and iPhone both have their own location API.
- figure out application deployment for the platform you picked. How does the mobile application get on the device? A phone manufacturer or network operator application store, a third party store like www.getjar.com, pre-installed on the phone via a partnership with the manufacturer or the network operator...plenty of options.
- come up with a sensible way of packaging mobile location data and send it over the network to a remote server.
- make a website to display the location data stored on the server.

Comment: thanks, that was helpfull
On the subject off different platforms, do you know by any chance
wich one is the easyast to implement. Or wich combination?